# How can I query double nested objects in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I'm using CouchDb in Fabric and I have the next JSON document

`{
    "id": "invoice1",
    "sellers": [{
        "names": "Clark",
        "items": [{
            "iditem": "item1",
            "properties": [{
                "width": "212cm"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}`

How can I query the width property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$elemMatch

Used something like this.

```
{
   "selector": {
      "sellers": {
         "$elemMatch": {
            "items": {
               "$elemMatch": {
                  "properties": {
                     "$elemMatch": {
                        "width": {
                           "$eq": "212cm"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Are there other way without use $eq?